# Extract x/y data from PolyCollection from fill_between

Tags: matplotlib

How can I extract the x/y data from the resulting PolyCollection from a `fill_between` plot?

```
polyCollection = ax.fill_between(x,ylo,yhi)
```

Now how do I get the data back from `polyCollection`?

For other `Collection` objects, I use `x, y = artist.get_offsets().T`, but here that returns just zeros for some reason.

For "Line" type objects, I use `x, y = artist.get_xdata(), artist.get_ydata()`.

(I use this information in a callback to locally auto-zoom the y-axis to fit the data within a certain x-range.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`polyCollection.get_paths()` gives a list of [paths](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path). In this case a list with one element. From there you can get the [vertices](https://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.vertices) as an Nx2 numpy array, and there the `x` and `y`:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 20
polyCollection = plt.fill_between(np.arange(0, N),
                                  5 + np.random.normal(size=N).cumsum(),
                                  10 + np.random.normal(size=N).cumsum(), color='lightblue', alpha=0.3)
points = polyCollection.get_paths()[0].vertices
xs = points[:, 0]
ys = points[:, 1]
plt.scatter(xs, ys, marker='o', color='crimson')
```

[image: example of resulting plot]