# Is it possible to retrieve the coordinates of colored areas from fill_between?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know the function `fill_between` from matplotlib allows to color space between curves. Now, I would like to know if I can retrieve this information, ie get the coordinates of the pixels that are now colored on my plotting window.

Here is a working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = np.linspace(0,20,100)
plt.plot(x,y)
im = plt.fill_between(x,y)
```

Here I see a blue triangle, how can I get the coordinates of the points within this triangle? I have been searching through the `PolyCollection` options, but nothing seems to fit what I want.

Here is an example of what `fill_between` looks like:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "the coordinates of the points"? There is an infinite number of points in this filled area. Maybe you want to calculate the area?

Comment: You're right, I guess what would help me is a method to test if a point is inside this area, or a way to get the area's boundaries.

Comment: What do you want to test? PolyCollection has the method `contains(mouseevent)` to test whether a mouse event occurs within this PolyCollection. Otherwise, I would consider using shapely. The paths can be extracted as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63078126/8881141).

Answer (score 0):

If you have functions `f(x) = y` and `g(x) = y` that describe the boundary lines, and you want to test whether a given point `(x, y)` lies between the graphs of these functions (i.e. within the area colored by `fill_between`), you can write a function like this:

```py
def is_between(x, y, f, g=lambda x: 0):
    y_min = f(x)
    y_max = g(x)
    if y_min > y_max:
        y_min, y_max = y_max, y_min
    return y_min <= y <= y_max
```

For example, is the point `(2, 4.1)` within the blue area in your example? In this case, we can omit specifying `g`, because we set it to be the x-axis (g(x) = 0) by default.

```py
is_between(2, 4.1, lambda x: 2 * x)
```

This returns `False`, as expected.

Comment: Good thinking but it lacks flexibility to be applicable to cases like [`fill_betweenx(y, x1, x2)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_betweenx_demo.html)